# How to use sql server 2005 stored procedures in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have just started a new web application with `asp.net mvc` and `sql server 2005`... Thus far in my webform applications i used `ADO.NET`... I want the same in my `asp.net MVC` apllication...

I have a database in `sql server 2005` with all the `stored procedures`... Now i want to use those stored procedures in my MVC application... I dont use any `ORM`... I want to use ADO.NET..

Any sample `controller` that calls a `model` which uses a `stored procedure` and returns a `Dataset` to the `controller` and then the `controller to View` to display records... Any suggestions...

Comment: Suggestion: We add tag ADO.Net and remove asp.net-mvc.

Comment: @Moron i want to use it with asp.net MVC

Comment: Isn't your main problem to use ADO.NET and call stored procedures? Does it really matter if you are using asp.net-mvc on top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommenced using a service or a repository that is responsible for populating the model with the data from the stored procedure that the controller sends to the view.  I'm not sure on the reasoning for avoiding ORMs with the desire to use ADO.NET.  The reality is entity framework, Linq2Sql, SubSoncic, and NHibernate are very proven and reliable.

Here is a quick sample I put together...  It uses the SqlConnection and SqlCommand to call the stored procedure...  Put this code in a separate class that the controller calls to get the Model.

```
    public BlogEntry GetBlogEntry(int blogId)
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
        sqlConnection.ConnectionString = MyConnectionString;
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
        sqlCommand.CommandText = "mySproc";
        sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
        sqlConnection.Open();
        var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();.
        var blogEntry = new BlogEntry();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            //do something to fill your model...
        }
        return blogEntry;   
    }
```

Comment: There should be a finally block, where connection and reader get closed.

Comment: Agreed!  I didn't test this or add proper exception handling. I wouldn't view this as a copy paste prod ready implementation.